# unable to reinitialize selectpicker after jquery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, bootstrap-selectpicker

Selectpicker is working as expected but when I try to reinitialize after jquery load function it shows "Nothing selected" in dropdown. Here is the code:

```
    jQuery('body').on('change', 'select[name=slot]', function() {
        if( jQuery( this ).val() !== "" )
        {
            jQuery(".country").removeClass('selectpicker');
            jQuery('.loader').removeClass('hidden');
            jQuery( "#container" ).load( window.location.href + " #innercontent" );
            setTimeout(function() {
                customVectorMap();
                jQuery("div.jvectormap-container svg").resize();
                google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawUsageChart);
                jQuery('.loader').addClass('hidden');
                jQuery('.country').addClass('selectpicker').selectpicker(); 
            }, 4000);
        }
    });
```

Jvectormap and google charts are working when we're reinitializing but only selectpicker isn't working. I also tried with

```
    jQuery('.country').addClass('selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: Instead of using setTimeout...load() has a complete callback.... `$(selector).load(url, function(){ /* new html exists here*/})`

Comment: Thank you but same result with it as well

Comment: What is actually happening? Hard to troubleshoot what we can't see. Also might need to destroy original.

Comment: @charlietfl , actually it's working with initial page load but when I change the slot(vpn functionality), we have to load the div and that div contains the selectpicker drop-down.

Comment: Here is the url where I placed demo code:

 https://www.starvpn.com/dashboard/selectpicker.php

and I used below code on slot selection:

`jQuery(document).ready( function(){
 jQuery('body').on('change', 'select[name=slot]', function() {
        if( jQuery( this ).val() !== "" )
        {
   jQuery('#container').load( window.location.href + " #innercontent", function(){ 
    jQuery('.country').selectpicker('refresh'); 
   });
        }
    });
});`

Comment: Your select is empty by default. How does it get the `<option>` elements? When I look at page source it has none. So whatever you do to insert them when page loads needs to be done again

Comment: Thank you for looking at the page source. Actually I had to call countrypicker function as well before call the selectpicker. Thank you for help @charlietfl